# Querying Webservice API

Tags: xml, web-services, api

Are there any Public WebService API that I can query and get the search results in XML?

Comment: Are you referring to Google search results?

Comment: Any public webservice api that return results in XML..Google is very common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty. One interesting place to explore might be [Yahoo's YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) (Yahoo Query Language) service. That provides access to many several different APIs with an interesting interface, and will return results as XML (or JSON.)

YQL makes it very easy to write a "query" against one or more web service APIs that you can then use as a single HTTP GET-style request to return you XML.